# Enterprise library for .NET

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

what enterprise library are you using for your enterprise projects? beside Microsoft Enterprise Library?

Thanks

Comment: Oh dear. "Enterprise library"...

Answer (score 3):

We use Web Client Software Factory, Composite Application Guidance - both are frameworks from Microsoft for building composite applications (web and wpf).

Answer (score 2):

EnterpriseLibrary, Log4Net, StructureMap for production code.
NUnit, RhinoMocks for test code.